# No means of detecting collision at the application layer? Hmm

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++, simulator, inet

Given the degree of uselessness one has come to expect from both tutorials

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/wireless/doc/step5.html

and manual pages:

https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:warmup:network

how can collision be modelled at the application layer?

Comment: Why close the question? It's clear that it's clear what's being asked. Lol, it has even been answered.

Comment: It was voted to be closed probably because it contained two unrelated questions. Also the title is a bit misleading because you are referring to "detecting collision" and in the follow up discussion it turns out that there is never a collision in your simulation. What you are looking is to detect whether a node got "out of range" of the sink.
On application layer (and in a lot of routing protocols where link breaking should be detected) it is done by periodically sending a message and on the receiving side using a timer to see whether you have not received something during that timer period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not find a tutorial *how can collision be modelled at the application layer* simply because in application layer **collisions do not occur**.
Generally, a collision may occur when some medium (or layer) cannot be accessed simultaneously by many elements. However, there is no such limitation for application layer. Application may send a packet in any time, that packed will be processed by the transport layer (TCP or UDP) and then it is sent to network layer. The network layer has a buffer so in the situation when at the same time two or more application send packets the conflict will not occur.

According the details presented in your question:

- *how can hostSink check whether hostA or hostB are still sending packets [originally: signals]?* Answer: `hostSink` cannot determine whether `hostA` is still sending packets. Simulation reflects the behavior of a real network and in real network host does not know whether the another host is still sending packets.
- *How does time "pass" in a simulation?* Answer: OMNeT++ is Discrete Event Simulator and according to Simulation Manual:

> A discrete event system is a system where state changes (events) happen at discrete instances in time, and events take zero time to happen.

It means that a simulation internally maintains variable called `currentSimtime`. At the beginning `currentSimtime=0`. When the first event (for example sending an ARP packet) is scheduled at, for example, t=0.003s, `currentSimtime` is set to 0.003s and the sending ARP packet is executed.

Comment: > Answer: hostSink cannot determine whether hostA is still sending packets. Simulation reflects the behavior of a real network and in real network host do not know whether the another host is still sending packets. This, by no means, can be true. If both hosts are sending packets, even if they "collide" they should make it to the sink's application layer ...

Comment: ... Even if arrival is out of sequence, BOTH packets should be received and discarded by the sink. The sink can record reception time and set a timer (logically, at least). If a packet is received from either host until the time expires, then yes the hosts are still sending packets to the sink.

Comment: 1. _even if they "collide" they should make it to the sink's application layer_ - not always. In your question you have mentioned UDP, and remember that UDP is an unreliable protocol. And when in a channel bit error rate is greater then 0, the packet may be removed in physical layer. UDP do not guarantee that every sent packet will achieve destination.

Comment: I'm using a medium with no noise/interference ; the packet shouldn't get corrupted. Or?

Comment: 2. _If a packet is received from either host until the time expires, _  - yes, this way you can determine that sender is still active. But in your question you have not mentioned that packets are sent in regular periods and that receiver knows the value of period.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to set up a timer; it's clear that simulation time =/= actual time (OS). How can I create a timer that waits X OMNET seconds?

Comment: _I'm using a medium with no noise/interference ; the packet shouldn't get corrupted. Or?_ Well, in the most cases it shouldn't be discarded. But remember that - as in real network - the buffer in the network layer has finite size, a buffer in MAC too.

Comment: The simulation time is completely different from the operating system time! I strongly encourage you to do [TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/).

Comment: Yes, the buffer has finite size, but I can control the packet injection rate; sending packets at 200ms intervals from at most 6 nodes is not that much (the buffer can never get filled, realistically)

Comment: Now, in your question there are several issues. According to SO rules, one question should rise only one problem. I would like to suggest dividing this question into several questions. Otherwise, I would vote to close this question.

Comment: Yes, the tutorial only shows timers set in the ned file https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part7/. I need finer grained control

Comment: Done! But please stop referencing these tutorials. Their utility in practice is rather low, or better yet, unapplicable.

Comment: I would not say inapplicable. At least TicToc step 3.6 "Modeling Processing Delay" clearly deals with how to implement timers in C++ code: https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part3/#36-modeling-processing-delay

As for the wireless tutorial, and the reference from the manual linked in the question, they are indeed unrelated to your problem.